# Add 5 time tap event to container in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to add 5 time tap event to container. I am using GestureDetector to get tap event. But I dont know how to achieve 5 time taps event in it. I want when user tap 5 times on container then I want to perform some operation in my app.

Comment: Create a state and on each tab, increment it.

Answer (score 1):

I achieved by doing following

```
GestureDetector(
  child: Image.asset(
    ImageLogo,
    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.30,
    fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
  ),
  onTap: () {
    tapCounter = 0;
    oldTimestamp = 0;
  },
  onDoubleTap: () {
    int currentTimestamp = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
    print('currentTimestamp $currentTimestamp');
    print('oldTimestamp $oldTimestamp');
    print('tapCounter $tapCounter');
    if (tapCounter == 0) {
      oldTimestamp = 0;
    }
    if (oldTimestamp == 0 ||
        currentTimestamp - oldTimestamp < 450) {
      tapCounter += 2;
      oldTimestamp = currentTimestamp;
      if (tapCounter == 6) {
        tapCounter = 0;
        oldTimestamp = 0;
        print('Do some operation');
      }
    } else {
      tapCounter = 0;
    }
  },
)
```

I am storing current time and comparing old and current time, this is because of when user stop tapping on container, it will reset the counter to 0.

Answer (score 0):

you can easily use a piece of state to achieve this, in the example below i used an `Opacity` widget to display an icon if `_counter == 5`, this may not be exactly what you want but based on the context of your question this is what i can give.

```dart
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  int _counter = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () => setState(() => _counter++),
      child: Container(
          child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text('Tap me'),
          Opacity(
            opacity: _counter == 5 ? 1 : 0,
            child: Icon(
              Icons.whatshot
            ),
          )
        ],
      )),
    );
  }
}
```